# Null memory address when passing variables between functions without pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, arguments

When I compile a program in XCode, I get a "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" error that points to the variables I am passing between functions.

In questions I have seen on Stack Overflow relating to this subject, I've seen errors where pointers and references were improperly used in functions, returning a memory location of "0", but I'm not using pointers or references, just a variable which was declared with global scope.

Would it be better to use pointers here?

My program is trying to split an array of input in half and then print them out side-by-side. I use one int function and two string functions that accept int arguments and exit with `return 0;`

Is there a particular problem with passing variables declared outside of a function between functions? I have tried using pointers and references, but these return the same memory address error.

EDIT: The problem was using `return 0;` for functions defined as strings. I changed the function type to void and simply used `return;` to exit the function. The memory access problem was fixed afterwards.

Comment: @John3136 My apologies. This was an error of reproducing my code into a different example just to try and simplify things. I've copied my full code into the questions if it makes things easier. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately, another error with my typing. The function was string in both cases in the original program. That was my bad.

Comment: The functions are supposed to return a string, but they contain `return 0`. And of course 0 isn't a string.

Comment: @BoPersson: that is true. So what ends up happening is the `std::string` is constructed with `0`, but there is no constructor that matches that input, but there is one that takes a `char*` pointer, and `0` is implicitly convertible to `char*`, so that is the constructor used, and constructing a `std::string` with a null `char*` pointer is **undefined behavior**

Comment: It's amazing how you people are able to debug thin air

Answer (score 0):

The return value matching the defined type of function was the correct answer, provided by @RemyLebeau and @BoPerrsson.